# Did you intend to use mongodb/mongodbatlas? If so, you must specify that │ source address in each module which requires that provider

Tags: terraform, mongodb-atlas

I have below in my provider.tf in the root directory

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.5"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "= 3.8.0"
    }
    mongodbatlas = {
      source = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting below error in `terraform init` stage

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/mongodbatlas: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not
│ have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/mongodbatlas
│ 
│ Did you intend to use mongodb/mongodbatlas? If so, you must specify that
│ source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which
│ modules are currently depending on hashicorp/mongodbatlas, run the
│ following command:
│     terraform providers
```

After this error, I included below in my `mongodb atlas` child module too which needed it and it worked.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mongodbatlas = {
      source = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"
    }
  }
}
```

My question is why do I need to do this? I don't have to do it for any other required providers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC, it is not an official Hashicorp provider so has to be defined expicitly.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 10):

**Just for visitors who are having the same error, follow the instructions**

Check the message:

> Did you intend to use mongodb/mongodbatlas? If so, you must specify
> that source address in each module which requires that provider.

You need to put your MongoDB provider inside each module you're using.

Run `terraform providers` and check which modules require MongoDB.

Create a **versions.tf** file inside each module.
Add the following code (with your desired version):

```js
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mongodbatlas = {
      source  = "mongodb/mongodbatlas",
      version = "1.8.0"
    }
  }
}
```

**About the need to put required_providers inside each module**

> **Testing Atlas Provider Versions that are NOT hosted on Terraform Registry (i.e. pre-release versions)**
>
> To test development / pre-release versions of the Terraform Atlas
> Provider that are not hosted on the Terraform Registry, you will need
> to create a Terraform Provider Network Mirror.
>
> The provider network mirror protocol is an optional protocol which you
> can implement to provide an alternative installation source for
> Terraform providers, regardless of their origin registries. Terraform
> uses network mirrors only if you activate them explicitly in the CLI
> configuration's provider_installation block. When enabled, a network
> mirror can serve providers belonging to any registry hostname, which
> can allow an organization to serve all of the Terraform providers they
> intend to use from an internal server, rather than from each
> provider's origin registry.

source: https://github.com/mongodb/terraform-provider-mongodbatlas

Answer (score 0):

similar question is answered here - [Terraform using both required_providers and provider blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080706/terraform-using-both-required-providers-and-provider-blocks)

gist - if the provider you are using is not one of the official provider by Terraform then you need to specify the terraform required_providers block to let terraform know the source to download the provider plugin.

LIST OF OFFICIAL PROVIDERS BY TERRAFORM - [link](https://registry.terraform.io/browse/providers?category=database%2Chashicorp%2Cinfrastructure-management%2Cpublic-cloud%2Casset%2Ccloud-automation%2Ccommunication-messaging%2Cvcs%2Cutility%2Cweb%2Csecurity-authentication%2Cplatform%2Clogging-monitoring%2Cnetworking%2Cinfrastructure%2Cdata-management%2Cci-cd%2Ccontainer-orchestration&tier=official)

Answer (score 0):

mongodb/mongodbatlas is not a hashicorp provider. You have to explicitly define required_providers in each module, as such providers are not inherited.

Comment: Am I right saying that this will automatically make this module a legacy module, on which you can't do foreach or depends_on?