# terraform mongodb provider configuration

Tags: mongodb, terraform

I am trying to create mongodb atlas cluster along with bunch of already created resources in aws

in main.tf

```
terraform {
  backend "pg" {
    conn_str = "sample"
  }
  required_providers {
    mongodbatlas = {
      source  = "mongodb/mongodbatlas"
      version = "~> 1.4"
    }
  }
}
<other modules>
module "mongodbatlas_db" {
  source        = "<file location>"
}
```

in mongo file, along with bunch of aws of other mongo stuff, basic project creation has this code

```
<bunch of aws stuff>
resource "mongodbatlas_project" "xname" {
  name   = "x_project"
  org_id = "x_org_id"

  teams {
    team_id    = "x_tem_id"
    role_names = ["GROUP_OWNER"]
  }
}
<bunch of other mongo stuff>
```

if i run

> terraform init

it tries to access hashicorp/mongodbatlas instead of mongodb/mongodbatlas
I have tried adding

> provider = mongodb.mongodbatlas

to resource configuration but it still uses same. Though it is succesfully downloading mongodb/mongodbatlas (from required providers configuration)

Similar question but unanswered
[Did you intend to use mongodb/mongodbatlas? If so, you must specify that │ source address in each module which requires that provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091344/did-you-intend-to-use-mongodb-mongodbatlas-if-so-you-must-specify-that-sourc)

Comment: What exactly do you have in your `module "mongodbatlas_db"`?

Comment: thats all there is (just source). its added in main.tf, since mongo conf is located in other file @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by moving required_providers config to same file as mongo. It should not be in base/any other files.
Source: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/google-terraform-mongodbatlas-provider-issue/27153/2